# smallerops sum in newtxmath

Tags: newtxmath

The `newtxmath` package has something called as `smallerops` option which when used causes the math largeoperators (other than integrals) to render 20% less than their original font size.

My question is the following: I would like to use smallerops option (in displaymath mode) only for the "Summation" (the default summation symbol is too big). Is this possible?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your objective: You wish to reduce the size of the symbol produced by `\sum` in displaymath mode, but not the size of other large math operators such as `\prod` and `\coprod`. Is this correct?

Comment: You could try `\medop{\sum}` (requires loading `nccmath`), which does the same job. Note that if you load `mathtools`, you should load nccmath first.

Comment: @Mico Yes you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve your objective, i.e., to get a smaller `\sum` symbol while leaving the sizes of `\prod`, `\coprod` and others unchanged, it suffices to copy l. 1327 from `newtxmath.sty` into the preamble of your document. (I'm currently using version 1.624 of `newtxmath.sty`, dated 2020/01/25.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\makeatletter  % See l. 1327 in newtxmath.sty:
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"50}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \sum \prod \coprod$
\end{document}
```